# Strategy.Close time based close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

timeSinceLastEntry()=> strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(strategy.opentrades-1)) : na
hoursSinceLastEntry = timeSinceLastEntry() / 1000 / 3600

//Action
if BuySig
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
strategy.close("My Long Entry Id", when = hoursSinceLastEntry == 1)

This should close a trade when it's been open for an hour. If plotting the "hoursSinceLastEntry", I see the counter works perfectly fine and it tracks the open trade time/hours. I made another variable H1Close to make it a series bool asking if hoursSinceLastEntry >= 1. Tested that with a plot as well and it fired "true".

However, even when both of these fire as "true" the strategy.close function does not close the trades. Why??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that of scope - the strategy.close was only executing within the local function of the "BuySig"